# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have to set the cookie value on the button click. The return value is just a success/failure message. I am using php for set cookie. I am using jquery ajax() for making request. but when i click on the button nothing is happening and i am getting an error message as "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested" in the error console.

The following is my ajax call,

```
    $('#visitors').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'http://site_url/setCoocky.php?action=SET_COOCKIE&user=visitor',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
                    /* beforeSend: function (request) {

                        //request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ", "*")
                        },*/

                    success:function(resp){
                        window.location.href = site_url+"#!/pageHome";
                    }
                });

        });
```

please help me..

Thanks& regards,
johncy binoy

Comment: This means that the server is not configured to allow cross domain requests.  If you cannot modify the server configuration, then you should see if the server supports JSONP which can be used cross domain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://wordicious.com' is therefore not allowed access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433655/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-or)

Comment: Spelling it *setCoocky* just seems so very wrong

Comment: Is the JavaScript part of the same site as `site_url`? If so, don't use a full URI, simply use a relative path, eg `url: '/setCooky.php', data: {action: 'SET_COOKIE', user: 'visitor'}`