# Unable to bind data in ajax through webapi

Tags: ajax

I am getting data by verifying through "jsonp"  but it is going to error.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: _BaseUrl,
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    processData: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data) {
            sourceGrid = data;
        return true;
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR.error);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Error is:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load url. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin url is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433655/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-or. Sounds like you are doing a cross domain ajax call, you should find a suitable solution in the link provided.

Answer (score 0):

Please mention URL you are using for AJAX.. One reason could be you are using full url with http.. Try relative URL.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer.Need to call a class which contains in detail to allow access.