# How to use the load () method of jQuery in the Meteor? There native better alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, meteor

I'm using Meteor. I need to get and display data from a site. I'm trying to do this with jQuery, but is not working. What do I do? There is a native of Meteor method to do this?

Example:

```
Template.test.helpers({
  load: function () {
    $(".first").load("http://www.jekyllrb.com");
  return $(".p")}
});
```

---

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> test}}
</body>

<template name="test">
  {{load}}
</template>
```

The result is the array `[object] [Object]`. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions come to my mind.

**The first solution:**

Use onRendered hook:

```
Template.test.onRendered(function() {
  $(".first").load("http://www.jekyllrb.com");
});
```

You have to have an element with class *first* in your template:

```
<template name="test">
  <div class="first"></div>
</template>
```

**The second solution:**

Use [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp):

```
<template name="test">
  <iframe src="http://www.jekyllrb.com"></iframe>
</template>
```

**EDIT:** You may get `"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."` error when you try to load page with `$(".first").load("http://www.jekyllrb.com");` I made it work [omitting www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433655/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-or):

```
Template.test.onRendered(function() {
  $(".first").load("http://jekyllrb.com");
});
```

Comment: The template did not work, the Iframe yes. I found no way to load only specific selector? Thank you!

Comment: I updated the answer. I tested it and I can see jeklyyrb.com inside the .first class

Comment: It worked! I understand the basic operation of onRendered. Thanks a lot!