# Jquery and servlet communication with ajax

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I want to establish a communication between a Jquery function and a servlet in tomcat.

**Servlet Code:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



public class Test extends HttpServlet {
public static String getBody(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

    String body = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } else {
            stringBuilder.append("");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
    body = stringBuilder.toString();
    return body;
}
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        System.out.println(getBody(request));
        out.println("Success Call Ajax POST");

      }
    public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
        response ) throws ServletException, IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" );
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Get Method");

  }

}
```

The servlet identity is defined in web.xml

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.servlets.Test</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/toto</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And the following HTML contains the JQuery function:

**Jquery code:**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function login(){  

      $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "http://localhost:8080/test/toto",  
        data: "POST Call",
        success: function(result){  
          alert("success call"+result);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        }                 
      });  
    }        
    </script>
    <title>My AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="login()">Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

I tested the servlet with the browser, it's fine. When I tried the HTML/js app and I clicked in the button I got in the eclipse console the message displayed by the instruction System.out.println(getBody(request)); "POST Call" but I got in the browser the error alert. So ajax function call successfully the method post in the servlet but the servlet can't return successfully the response to the browser. It seems that there's a problem in the servlet. Can someone help me please?

Comment: If it is showing 'POST Call' , there might be issues in `data: "POST Call",` in ajax..  Also check network tab for response and header, if you are using chrome browser.

Comment: I tried with firefox and chrome and I got the same error alert.
But in chrome I got also this error message when I click in the button:



            XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/test/toto. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: are you loading the servlet using an iframe?\

Comment: No I don't use the iframe load

Comment: I just simulated your code in a Web Application and works fine!!! The only thing that could be wrong is the application name.... Are you sure you can access `http://localhost:8080/test/` ? Is this the root of your application?

Comment: You are making a cross origin request. You should probably look into this link for further detals
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Comment: @MaVRoSCy: yes the servlet app is working fine without any problem.

Comment: In the `doPost()` try adding the request header : `response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` does it make any difference?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy: your suggestion saved me

Comment: ok i will add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `doPost()` try adding the request header :

```
response.setContentType("text/html"); 
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

I am certain that this has to do with the Allow Origin problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433655/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-or)

Answer (score 0):

It is browser specific.

Its works fine on Safari 8.0.3, it throws error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present` on Chrome and Firefox.

Look at console in Firefox:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/toto. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

It could be fixed by disabling `web security` in browser or as already mentioned:

`response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", your_domain);`