# Errors with AWS SimpleDB Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-web-services, cors, amazon-simpledb

I'm trying to use AWS SimpleDB Javascript SDK.
Here's the web page with my script:

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4111969/aws-sdk-2.1.39.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'MYKEY', secretAccessKey: 'MYSECRET'});
           AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
           AWS.config.logger = console;
        </script>

        <script>
           var simpledb = new AWS.SimpleDB({region:'us-east-1'});
           var params = { MaxNumberOfDomains: 1 };

           simpledb.listDomains(params, function(err, data) {
              if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
              else console.log(data);           
           });
        </script>

      </body>
  </html>
```

When I run this web page I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://sdb.amazonaws.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

I think this is due to CORS policy. But I can't find a way to setup CORS for SimpleDB so I installed an [AddOn](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) into the browser which allows to request any site with ajax from any source.

With the AddOn turned on I get a different error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://sdb.amazonaws.com/. Invalid HTTP status code 400

I tried running this script from a local file and hosted it on AWS S3. I still get the same error. I'm sure the database exist on my account and I can access it with other tools. But I need to access it with JavaScript. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** [More information from the browser console](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4111969/log.txt)

Comment: May be related- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433655/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-or

Comment: Could you possibly post your request to the server and the server's response? It may be possible that some headers are missing or incorrect for one reason or another.

Comment: @VaughnOkerlund I'm not sure exactly where to get that information from. But I made a copy of everything I could find in the browser console: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4111969/log.txt

Comment: Possibly related: AWS Support says [CORS isn't supported on SimpleDB](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=526584#526584) circa 2014.

Comment: @devonlazarus Thanks to your link I found an answer: The AWS Javascript SDK is actually built for both browser and server-side usage, which is why many services which do not include explicit CORS support are available.

The Javascript in the Browser SDK explicitly supports the following services: DynamoDB, SNS, STS, S3, SQS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=147151&tstart=0) forum post:

> While it is possible to use SimpleDB with the Javascript in the browser SDK, as you have noted, this requires CORS to be disabled on the client side.
>
> The AWS Javascript SDK is actually built for both browser and server-side usage, which is why many services which do not include explicit CORS support are available.
>
> The Javascript in the Browser SDK explicitly supports the following services:
> DynamoDB, SNS, STS, S3, SQS

Turns out it's currently impossible to use SimpleDB AWS SDK over http.
The [request](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=147151&tstart=0) to add CORS support was submitted on 27 Feb 2014, but looks like it hasn't been implemented yet.