# Not Able To Make Real Payment in Facebook Game

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-payments

I am trying to implement facebook payment in Unity game for Webgl build. It is working fine when I pay as a tester but when I am trying to purcahse by real money it is giving me following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://apps.secure.facebook.com/ajax/payment/token_proxy.php?tpe=%2Fpayments%2Fcredit_card%2Fmutator%2Fcreate%2F&__a=1.
>   The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'https://apps.secure.facebook.com' that is not equal to the supplied
>   origin. Origin 'https://apps.facebook.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

What does this mean and how do I solve it?

Comment: did you resolve the issue? I have the same one at the moment

Comment: No,Just mention bug in facebook bug dashboard

Comment: Bugs solved ,Please update facebook sdk.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide a link to the bug in facebook dashboard please?

Answer (score 3):

The script is limited by the "same origin policy" which means a page can send requests to a server with **exactly** the same domain name. In your case, the page'https://apps.facebook.com' is trying to send a request to the domain name 'https://apps.secure.facebook.com'. As u can see, there is a difference in the domain names. They differ by the 'secure' word.
For more information on this problem and solution for it, refer this page - [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '...' is therefore not allowed access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433655/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-or?rq=1)

Comment: But this is bugs from facebook side.How we can solve that  ? I am seeing some game made on Unity working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change the reference of `https://apps.facebook.com` to `https://apps.secure.facebook.com` or vice-versa.

Comment: But i dont have access to change in Facebook sdk.Can you suggest me how can i do that ?

Comment: If there's nowhere for you to change the server name, make sure, then this should be reported to Facebook.