# newbie jquery/ajax: why error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've made this simple html page but get "error" alert popup when calling example.com.  Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function errorAlert(e, jqxhr) {
                alert("Your request was not successful: " + jqxhr);
            }
            function processData() {
                alert("success")
            }
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "post",
                url: "http://example.com",
                success: processData,
                error: errorAlert
            }); //end of $.ajax
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm running on Chrome 45.0...

Answer (score 0):

You can see different types of JavaScript errors in the developer console (F12 in Google Chrome).
You will see: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Take a look here for a detailed explanation: [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '...' is therefore not allowed access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433655/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-or)

But basically, the host you send the request to must match the origin, or explicitly allow foreign hosts.