# Android WebView "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to load a test web page (in my server). Page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=1"/>

</body>
</html>
```

But webView is not loading page. Not even onProgressChanged called after %40-50

Also, this problem occurs all sites that loads js script from url. Including **youtube, fb** etc.

```
WebConsole: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.youtube.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here my settings

```
    FrameLayout contentFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.ContentFrame);
    WebView mWebView = new WebView(this);

    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://ozgur.dk/browser.html");

    contentFrame.removeAllViews();
    contentFrame.addView(mWebView);
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/ContentFrame"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Comment: Please refer similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433655/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-or

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are not pausing timers in somewhere? Because this happens when you call `mWebView.pauseTimers()` when page loading.

Comment: Thanks so much, I wasn't aware that I'm pausing timer in other parts of activity.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this by enabling a WebSetting called [setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs%28boolean%29)
This is happening on the Javascript layer.
You can read up about it here : [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do a cross-domain request, which is impossible since it's on a different domain than your page is on.

**There is however a workaround that.**

[Using CORS - tutorial by Monsur Hossain](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

An example using CORS (By Monsur Hossain):

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {

// Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
// "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
xhr.open(method, url, true);

} else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

// Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
// XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
xhr = new XDomainRequest();
xhr.open(method, url);

} else {

// Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
xhr = null;

}
return xhr;
}

var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
if (!xhr) {
throw new Error('CORS not supported');
}
```

---

As a side note, if you want to run JavaScript on Android:

[Execute JavaScript in Android without WebView - tutorial by Wesley Lin](http://lifeofcoding.com/2015/04/05/Execute-JavaScript-in-Android-without-WebView/)

An example using Rhino (by Wesley Lin):

```
Object[] params = new Object[] { "javaScriptParam" };

// Every Rhino VM begins with the enter()
// This Context is not Android's Context
Context rhino = Context.enter();

// Turn off optimization to make Rhino Android compatible
rhino.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
try {
Scriptable scope = rhino.initStandardObjects();

// Note the forth argument is 1, which means the JavaScript source has
// been compressed to only one line using something like YUI
rhino.evaluateString(scope, javaScriptCode, "JavaScript", 1, null);

// Get the functionName defined in JavaScriptCode
Object obj = scope.get(functionNameInJavaScriptCode, scope);

if (obj instanceof Function) {
    Function jsFunction = (Function) obj;

    // Call the function with params
    Object jsResult = jsFunction.call(rhino, scope, scope, params);
    // Parse the jsResult object to a String
    String result = Context.toString(jsResult);
}
} finally {
Context.exit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.
Better install security certificate on your server.
**still**
To circumvent add following line in Manifest

```
<application
        ...
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...
```

viola...