# Code igniter installation in subfolder throw CORS in XMLhttprequest

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, codeigniter, cors

I have installed codeigniter application in a subfolder, whenever i send ajax request i get this error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

My config.php is:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://jmwglobal.com/locker/';
```

I don't know why i am getting this error. I have tried almost all remedies available on internet/stackoverflow but no solution found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, It was deeply written in somewhere in STACKOVERFLOW.

Thanks to this post. 
[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '...' is therefore not allowed access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433655/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-or)

**JavaScript code is limited by the same-origin policy, meaning, from a page at www.example.com, you can only make (AJAX) requests to services located at exactly the same domain, in that case, exactly  www.example.com (not example.com - without the www - or whatever.example.com).**

What I did is i just put these two lines in my htaccess,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

These line actually remove www from URL. This is important because as @acdcjunior Said in the above post that `www.domain.com` is different from `domain.com` for javascript.

BIG THANKS TO @acdcjunior.