# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Google finance converter gives an error javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-finance

I'm working with one project module, where I want to get converted price from Google finance converter based on from currency code and amount.
Here is my code:

```
$('.actual-price').tooltip({
    content: function(callback) {
        var url = 'https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=25&from=USD&to=AMD';
        $.get(url, {}, function(data) {            
            callback(data);
        });
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
        var $id = $(ui.tooltip).attr('id');
        $('div.ui-tooltip').not('#' + $id).remove();
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui - tooltip').hide();
    }
});
```

It gives me an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   `https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=25&from=USD&to=AED`. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin `http://mytestsite.com` is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I've tried following ways to solve it, but seems like nothing works for me!

First:
Added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the web config.

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Second: Using datatype jsonp:

```
dataType: "jsonp",
```

And already referred following posts:

[“No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err)

[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '…' is therefore not allowed access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433655/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-or)

[“No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

*Side: It's working with my localhost, but when I try with another domain, it's give me an error!*

Comment: You are calling https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=25&from=USD&to=AMD this url but this url not return anything they display html form so you cannot call using $.get

Comment: @PareshGami: Then why it is working with my localhost?

Comment: if you put it in live server that is working you mean?

Comment: @PareshGami:  *It's working with my localhost, but when I try with another domain, it's give me an error!*

Comment: What happen when you install this to your browser? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: @SamuelTulach: Thanks! It works on chrome, but I'm developing a  product(plugin) for end users, wherein I can't ask end users to install specific browser and extension!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS you could take a look at this, if it still isn't solved yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allow access origin must be allowed **also at side, when you sending requests**. If not you can install some [browser extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) to bypass it or download entire page (php) end then process it, but you can also try [cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com):

```
var myUrl = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=216.58.209.68';

var proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';

var finalURL = proxy + myUrl;

// With the get JSON (frequently used) method
$.getJSON(finalURL, function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
});

// With the get method
$.get(finalURL, function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
});

// With the post method
$.post(finalURL, function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

[More here](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/73/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin-error-with-xmlhttprequest-jquery-ajax-).

And why is your app working on localhost host? I thing it is because Google have access origin set to allow connection from their domains and localhost.

Comment: For me it is working normally: https://jsfiddle.net/7uvd8s69/1/. You may have bad address.

Comment: Okay, let me check once again, will let you know!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change Ajax Setting `async: false` as below:

JavaScript Code:

```
$('.actual-price').tooltip({
    content: function(callback) {
        var url = 'https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=25&from=USD&to=AMD';
        $.ajaxSetup({async: false}); ////////// Added
        $.get(url, {}, function(data) {            
            callback(data);
        });
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
        var $id = $(ui.tooltip).attr('id');
        $('div.ui-tooltip').not('#' + $id).remove();
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui - tooltip').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an error when you try to make requests to another servers from local without a web server, if you are using chrome on local, [just add this to your browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

when you upload the app to the server in production will work normally. because that's just a local problem that the browser block that types of requests.

Comment: I'm developing a product(plugin) for end users, wheres I can't ask end users to install specific browser and extension!

Comment: as I said, this will happen just on your local on development, when the app is on production, this wouldn't happen

Comment: Then that is not a solution!! see the comment by Samuel, just under the question.

Comment: and that is not a problem for you anymore, really, that is just a problem on development mode and you can install an extension or put your app in a web server that let you make cross domain request. that in local is not neccesary so you install a plugin to solve this on development, but in production mode, when you deploy the app, that is not a problem because don't happen. I was in the same with ruby on rails and that's the solution. don't keep wasting time. try starting your app on production mode and see if the error is there, it wouldn't be.

Comment: another option is to use jsonp with jquery but as I said, that is not necesary. have a good day my friend

Comment: Okay, I've tried with jsonp but it didn't work, let me give some time to run on production, then will let you know, thank you so much for detailed response :)

Comment: I've tested on my live production server, error comes there too!