# flot chart pulling data from mysql ajax js

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, charts, flot

i'm trying to pull  data from a mysql database and plot in a flot chart. i've seen dozens of posts but it's not working for me.
I successfully get flot charts working in php
http://oven.luckybat.space/batoven1.0_s.php

firstly here's the url for the data
intellipool.overcast.net.au/PCsystem/getdataforflot.php
it seems to be in the correct format.
i want to plot temperature versus time

I get an 'error alert' when i load the page that runs this script

there is a

```
     <p> id="graph3" style="width:1000px;height:500px;">graph3</p>
```

on the wordpress webpage

help appreciated

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'http://intellipool.overcast.net.au/PCsystem/getdataforflot.php',


    error: function() {
      alert("An error occurred.");
    },
  success: function(data) {
    alert("got the data dude");
    var options = {
      xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        mintickSize: [1, "hours"],
        axisLabel: 'Time',
        min: ((new Date().getTime()) - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        max: (new Date()).getTime()
      },
      yaxes: [{
        tickFormatter: function(val, axis) {
          return val + "\u00B0C";
        },
        max: 50,
        axisLabel: "Temperature",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelPadding: 5
      }, {
        position: "right",
        tickFormatter: function(val, axis) {
          return val + "%";
        },
        max: 100,
        axisLabel: "Humidity",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelPadding: 10
      }],
    };
    $.plot("#graph3", data, options);
  }

});
```

as per instructions i've added

```
         <header> ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); </header>
```

to http://intellipool.overcast.net.au/PCsystem/getdataforflot.php

i'm still getting the error, do i need to do more on the server (by contacting hosting?)

do i need to assign JSON data coming in to a variable?

the full function() is

```
 function ajaxplot() {  
 document.write('hello!! there ajaxplot() AJAX has been called');
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://intellipool.overcast.net.au/PCsystem/getdataforflot.php',

    error: function() {
    alert("An error occurred.");
  },
success: function(data) {
   alert("got the data dude");
   var options = {
    xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    mintickSize: [1, "hours"],
    axisLabel: 'Time',
     min: ((new Date().getTime()) - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
     max: (new Date()).getTime()
  },
  yaxes: [{
    tickFormatter: function(val, axis) {
      return val + "\u00B0C";
    },
    max: 50,
    axisLabel: "Temperature",
    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
    axisLabelPadding: 5
  }, {
    position: "right",
    tickFormatter: function(val, axis) {
      return val + "%";
    },
    max: 100,
    axisLabel: "Humidity",
    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
    axisLabelPadding: 10
  }],
};
$.plot("#graph3", data, options);
}

 });
}
```

Comment: it just shows `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`  what this error means you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20434788/2534646)

Comment: so the $ajax url need to be the exact same domain as the website where the js code is??

Comment: Yes that's what exactly the problem is do you have rights to the server which you're calling `http://intellipool.overcast.net.au/PCsystem/getdataforflot.php` ? if yes than you must have to `Enable CORS` to the server

Comment: i've moved the $ajax url file to http://overcast.net.au/getdataforflot.p‌​hp, still not woking! if i move all the .js files as well would that work? i can ask the webhoster whether he can change 'enable CORS to the server

Comment: here's the test http://overcast.net.au/js-tests/

Comment: ohh that's not an issue you just put this on top of getdataforflot.php

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` and than try to access with same ajax function and make sure your syntax for ajax function is valid in your question it's invalid need some correction let me know if u r not able to correct

Comment: some correction has been made in question now it's syntactically fine

Comment: i've tried and failed! the question has been updated with what i've done

Comment: ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
[[1496765558000,"26"],[1496764656000,"26"],

Comment: appears before the data on http://intellipool.overcast.net.au/PCsystem/getdataforflot.php is that an issue?

Comment: remove `document.write('hello!! there ajaxplot() AJAX has been called');` from function

Answer (score 0):

Open your `http://overcast.net.au/js-tests/` link open console write below function

```
function ajaxplot() {   
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'json',
  url: '/getdataforflot.php',
  error: function() {
      alert("An error occurred.");
    },
  success: function(data) {
    debugger;
    alert("got the data dude");
    //var data1 = [[1496765558000,"26"],[1496764656000,"26"],[1496763754000,"26"],[1496762851000,"26"],[1496761949000,"26"]];
    var data1 = data;
    var options = {
      xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        mintickSize: [1, "hours"],
        axisLabel: 'Time',
         min: ((new Date().getTime()) - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
         max: (new Date()).getTime()
      },
      yaxes: [{
        tickFormatter: function(val, axis) {
          return val + "\u00B0C";
        },
        max: 50,
        axisLabel: "Temperature",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelPadding: 5
      }, {
        position: "right",
        tickFormatter: function(val, axis) {
          return val + "%";
        },
        max: 100,
        axisLabel: "Humidity",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelPadding: 10
      }],
    };
    $.plot("#graph3", data1, options);
    },

});
}
```

**THEN**

call `ajaxplot()` in console it should work.

See screenshot
[image]

In your console there are many errors resolve all and it should work..