# -- No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: javascript, angular, laravel, ionic-framework

while trying to access **`http:Localhost:9000/api/post`** from provider i get this error

> `Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access. is therefore not allowed access`

any knows what is wrong.

Comment: looks like it is server configuration issue, not angular, you must setup 'CORS' configuraion on your server side

Comment: Apache HTTP Server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '...' is therefore not allowed access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433655/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-or)

Comment: @brk I didn't get any solution from those.

Comment: @zainudinnoori Please read the dup post again, your answer is included in the answers on the linked dup.

Comment: may be this link can be usefull:https://gist.github.com/technoknol/1a35ca4b150215f491d5c807940bd4ef

Answer (score 1):

**Your front and back end are on different ports which means your ajax requests are subject to cross origin security.**

You need to do changes at your back-end api (server side) by adding

**Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*";**

in response headers according to the language you are using php,java or python e.t.c.