# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mydomainname.net' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: ajax, header, request, cors

So I've read all the other posts such as

[Similar Problem 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433655/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-or)

[Similar Problem 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

but neither solution works for me.

**So I have the following JavaScript code**

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "react.php?do=getnotify&rand=" + Math.random(), true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://mydomainname.net");
xhttp.send();
```

**Still I get the error**

> (index):1 Failed to load
>   http://mydomainname.net/react.php?do=getnotify&rand=0.10280796901744726:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://mydomainname.net' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

- **This only occurs when the user visits the website by going to *mydomainname.net***
- If the user visits the site by going to *www.mydomainname.net* then the Ajax request works fine - no issues.

So what gives???

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header, not a request header. You can’t set it from your frontend JavaScript code. Instead the server you’re making the request to needs to send an Access-Control-Allow-Origin. But the code shown in the question couldn’t cause the error message shown in the question — because that isn’t making a cross-origin request.

Comment: The URLs in the error message shown in the question don’t make sense; the browser would never report a message with *Failed to load `http://mydomainname.net/react.php?…` … Origin '`http://mydomainname.net`'* — because `http://mydomainname.net/react.php?…` has the same origin as `http://mydomainname.net`, so that wouldn’t be a cross-origin request, and so you wouldn’t get that error message.

Comment: @sideshowbarker  i dont know... its my host... so I can add anything I want to the .htaccess if you have any recommendations.  This script is on the home page of the site so.... like I said if you visit the home page of the site by typing in **www.mydomainname.net** then the script works fine... if you visit the home page by typing in **mydomainname.net** then the script fails because I guess the server considers **`http://mydomainname.net/blahblah`** an outside request where as it considers **`http://www.mydomainname.net/blahblah`** an internal request....basically I guessany advice?

Comment: in addition:
since javascript automatically prepends the domain in the address bar to the Ajax **`/react.php ....`** reference its pretty much impossible to ensure that **www** is in the Ajax address.  So I guess the question is.... how do I make the browser/server accept calls to **`http://mydomainname.net/blahblah`** and not just **`http://www.mydomainname.net/blahblah`**?

Comment: @sideshowbarker any suggestions?

Comment: The solution is to make your server send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header in responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was (what may be a bandaid... but it works) putting this in the **.htaccess** file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

so as to force **www** to be included at the beginning of the url.